# What is the proper way to handle asynchronicity in nodeunit?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nodeunit

I'm brand-spanking new to the whole stack - javascript, node.js, coffeescript, nodeunit. Think I should do it step by step? You're probably right, but I still am not going to do it.

Here is the test file:

```
testCase = require('nodeunit').testCase

Server = require('./web').WebServer
Client = require('../lib/client').Client
Request = require('../lib/request').Request

OPTIONS = {host: 'localhost', port: 8080, path: '/', method: 'GET'}
SERVER = new Server OPTIONS.port
CLIENT = new Client
REQUEST = new Request OPTIONS
SERVER.start() # asynchronous!

module.exports = testCase
  setUp: (callback) ->
    callback()

  tearDown: (callback) ->
    callback()

  testResponseBodyIsCorrect: (test) ->
    test.expect 1
    process.nextTick ->
      CLIENT.transmit REQUEST #asynchronous!
      process.nextTick ->
        test.equal REQUEST.body, /Ooga/
        test.done()
```

Internally, it is just a wrapper around the http library. I am using node 0.4.11.
This does not actually work. There are two asynchronous calls here. If I do this manually in the coffee REPL, it works -- but nodeunit is much faster than I am, so I run into something which, to be clever, I'll call a race condition. *grin*

Here is the implementation of 'transmit':
Http = require 'http'

```
exports.Client = class Client

  transmit: (request, callback = null) ->
    req = Http.request request.options, (res) ->
      res.setEncoding 'utf8'
      res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        request.appendToResponseBody chunk
    req.end()

    console.log "Request sent!"
```

I need to make sure the server gets bound to the port before I run the test, and I need to make sure ".transmit" has finished its internal callbacks to get the response before I do the assertion.

What is the clean way (or at least the way that works) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do something asynchronous, you should put the rest of your code in the callback from that async function. So instead of

CLIENT.transmit REQUEST
   process.nextTick -> ...

do

CLIENT.transmit REQUEST, (response) -> ...

(I'm assuming that your `CLIENT.transmit` method is implemented in such a way that it calls a callback with the response it gets—it should!)

Now, if you're trying to test the client and the server at the same time, then you should use an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html)—I think that you'll find that your `SERVER` object already is one, since it inherits from Node's [http.Server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.Server) type. Since `http.Server` objects fire a `request` event whenever they receive a request, you can do things like

```
SERVER.on 'request', (request) ->
  test.equals REQUEST.body, request.body
```

Pretty nice, right? Node-style asynchronicity can be mind-bending, but it gives you an amazing array of options.

Comment: Things are beginning to coalesce (I love that word and rarely get to use it). I have edited the question to add the implementation of 'transmit' - which, I am fairly sure, is bad. I think I see.. So the 'on response' callback is THE callback, which means I should pass that in - and passing another callback is meaningless. Correct?

Comment: Oh! And so that means that, eventually, my client or request wrapper/interface should also implement or inherit such events instead of relying on http's low-level ones, if I want to build a higher interface.. Since the http.request() stuff happens inside the client, the events probably don't bubble up magically, right?

Comment: Right, the nice thing about Node is that there's no magic; everything is on the surface. So currently, that `callback` argument that's passed in to `transmit` never gets called. What you need is `res.on 'end', -> callback? res`, which will pass the response to the `callback` function (if it exists) when it's been completely received.